# Adding product attributes to opencart invoice

Tags: php, attributes, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to show product attributes on the Print Invoice page in `Opencart` version `2.0.1.1`.

So far I have edited `admin/controller/sale/order.php` by adding `$this->load->model("catalog/product");`

Then I have added 'attribute' => `$this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($product['product_id'])` to the `$product_data[] = array()`

Now on the `order_invoice.tpl` page I have used `<?php print_r ($attribute);?>` to see what data it is pulling and it shows:

```
Array
(
[attribute_id] => 1
[product_attribute_description] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [text] => 240
            )

    )

)
```

The `[text] => 240` is the value of the attribute but I cannot for the life of me get the attribute name to show up, I have tried numerous attempts and as most commonly suggested I've tried `$attribute['name'];` but this brings up nothing.

Can someone please explain how I can properly retrieve the attribute name and attribute value.

Comment: thanks for doing some effort and posting your trials, I'll answer your question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried $attribute['name']; but this brings up nothing

So why do you think it should bring up something? obviously, there is no such an entry called `name` in `$attribute` (you can notice that in the dump you got through `print_r`)

Accordingly you need to change `$this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes` in such a way that it returns the name of the attribute, so in order to use `$attribute['name']` correctly, your `$attribute` dump should be like:

```
Array
(
[attribute_id] => 1
[name] => 'bla bla bla'
[product_attribute_description] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [text] => 240
            )

    )

)
```

So here is what we are going to do (sorry for the long intro):

1. open the file `<OC_ROOT>/admin/model/catalog/product.php`
2. go to the function `getProductAttributes($product_id)` @ class `ModelCatalogProduct`
3. Before this line `$product_attribute_data[] = array(`, we should add a query to get the attribute name:

```
// attribute name is stored in the table `attribute_description`
$attr_name_query = $this->db->query("SELECT `name` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "attribute_description` WHERE `attribute_id` = " . (int)$product_attribute['attribute_id'] . " and `language_id` = " . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id'));         
$attr_name = $attr_name_query->row['name'];
```

4. Finally, add `$attr_name` to the resultant attributes array, after the line `'attribute_id' => $product_attribute['attribute_id'],` add `'name' => $attr_name`

Comment: Abdo this is the perfect answer, thank you for your help on this. I had another look after my original post and noticed the model page was only generating attribute_id and product_attribute_description but I would have been stuck on how to get the name added to it.

Comment: @JamesCollins you are welcome, please use the term `model class` instead of `model page`